# How can I find the boundary function in RegionPlot?

Tags: graphics, equation-solving

I have a problem with finding the function that gives the boundary curve in `RegionPlot` comamnd. I use the following code to make the regions in which two inequalities are held simultaneously

```
RegionPlot[{{x^3 - y^2 > 2 y && x^2 + y^3 > 2 x }, 
            {x^3 - y^2 < 2 y && x^2 + y^3 > 2 x }}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, .1}, 
           PlotStyle -> {Green, Yellow}, BoundaryStyle -> {Black, Thick}]
```

[image]

Here we see a black thick curve between the green and yellow regions, I mean the boundary that separates these regions (I showed it with a red arrow) .

Now, how can I find its equation or at least the list of points living on this curve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "canonical" way is to find a pattern (here, `{Black, Thick}`) that matches what the boundary is made of and extract it from the graphics object.
So given

```
pt = RegionPlot[{{x^3 - y^2 > 2 y && 
     x^2 + y^3 > 2 x}, {x^3 - y^2 < 2 y && x^2 + y^3 > 2 x}}, {x, -1, 
   1}, {y, -1, .1}, PlotStyle -> {Green, Yellow}, 
  BoundaryStyle -> {Black, Thick}];

bdy=Cases[Normal@First@pt, {Black, Thick, __}, Infinity];

Graphics[bdy]
```

[image]

**---EDIT 2---**

In diagonally reading your question, I missed the requirement for the boundary between the two.

The following will work on the particular dataset. First, you can extract the points from the `bdy`:

```
points = Cases[bdy, Line[a___] -> a, Infinity]
```

and you will notice that there are two components each corresponding to one region. I thought that `Intersection` wouldn't work for the two but as @eldo points out, it turns out it does:

```
bdy = First /@ GatherBy[Intersection@@points, First] (* so that there are no duplicate x coords*);
```

gives the boundary points which can be fitted to a model of your liking or interpolate or whatever:

```
 fit = Interpolation[bdy, InterpolationOrder -> 1];

Plot[fit[x], {x, -1, 0},  
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize -> Tiny, Point[points[[1]]~Join~points[[2]]]},
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}]
```

[image]

Comment: @gpap - Instead of working with "Nearest", couldn't one simply take the "Intersection" of the two components?

Comment: Ehmmmmmmm......I thought that wouldn't work as the points wouldn't be the same but it seems to be working fine. I think this is a bad answer as it stands so maybe I should delete alltoghether..

Comment: please leave your answer since it's instructive, esp. the "Nearest"-function which I didn't know so far. Maybe you could make an addendum with "Intersection". - superseded, thanks gpap :)

Answer (score 4):

```
ContourPlot[x^3 - y^2 == 2 y, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, .1},
            RegionFunction -> (#^2 + #2^3 > 2 # &)]
```

[image]

The following procedure contains additional condition which you've provided by range for `RegionPlot`: `{x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, .1}`.

```
Reduce[x^3 - y^2 == 2 y && x^2 + y^3 > 2 x && Abs[x] <= 1 && -1 <= y <= .1, 
       {x, y}, Reals]
```

> ```
> -1. <= x < 0 && y == -1. + Sqrt[1. + x^3]
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the `FullForm` of

```
rp = RegionPlot[{{x^3 - y^2 > 2 y && 
      x^2 + y^3 > 2 x}, {x^3 - y^2 < 2 y && x^2 + y^3 > 2 x}}, {x, -1,
     1}, {y, -1, .1}, PlotStyle -> {Green, Yellow}, 
   BoundaryStyle -> {Black, Thick}];
```

with

```
rp // FullForm
```

you can easily see that

```
q = rp[[1, 1]]
```

and

```
p = First@Last@rp[[1]][[2]][[2]][[1]]
```

yielding

```
pointsoncurve = q[[p]]
```

Now,

```
ListPlot[pointsoncurve, Joined -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 GridLines -> Automatic]
```

shows

[image]

It wouldn't be too difficult to "automate" this, esp. the finding of "p".

Comment: Of course, Kuba's answer is the right one here, but I leave mine in case the OP wants to see the list of points MM uses to draw the boundaries.

Comment: Well, I've not provided the list of points so it's ok. The problem is that OP wants only the part of the border that separates both regions and here's more than that.