# EdgeDetect for / find boundary of data in lists

Tags: list-manipulation, graphics, data

I assume this is a simple task, yet I could not find any documentation or question treating this problem:

Let's say we have a simple binary data set, in this case defining a shape of a circle

```
data = Flatten[Table[{x, y, If[x^2 + y^2 < 1, 1, 0]}, {x, -2, 2, 0.1}, {y, -2, 2, 0.1}], 1];
ListDensityPlot[data, InterpolationOrder -> 0]
```

Now I want to have the points forming the boundary of this object, in coordinates `{{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...}`.

It seems to be exactly what `EdgeDetect` is doing, but that function does not accept data points, only images. Is there a similar function for data points?

These posts are related, but not the same in my opinion:

1. [Finding edges of a parametrized function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/49087/how-can-i-find-the-boundary-function-in-regionplot)
2. [Finding the edge of the plot area](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88377/density-plot-with-list-data-and-preferable-boundary)
3. [Finding the edge of data set](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44694/how-to-extract-the-edge-from-a-set-of-points)

The last question (3) is probably the same but the input data format seems to be different than here and the data is not available anymore.

[image]

Comment: `ConvexHullMesh` if convex.

Comment: Thanks, but what if it's not convex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn the data into an image, apply EdgeDetect, and (if needed) translate back to ImageData:

```
data = Table[If[x^2 + y^2 < 1, 1, 0], {x, -2, 2, 0.1}, {y, -2, 2, 0.1}];
edge = EdgeDetect[Image[data]]
edgeData = Table[{(x - 21)/10, (y - 21)/10, 
                 ImageData[edge][[x, y]]}, {x, 41}, {y, 41}];
```

The final line puts the {x,y} coordinates with the edges.

Comment: It works. However, I would suggest as a general approach to keep extract the `{x,y}` coordinates in a slightly different way. The function `f[data_, component_] := 
  Reverse[Partition[data[[All, component]], 
    Length[DeleteDuplicates[data[[All, 2]]]]]]` extracts one of the components of data and brings it to the `{nx,ny}` image shape. Then, `edgeData =Transpose[{Flatten[f[data,1]], Flatten[f[data,2]], Flatten[ImageData[edge]]}]` (where `data` is defined as in my post).

Comment: Just realized one typo in `f`. To be robust, it should read `f[data_, component_] := Module[{sdata},
   sdata = 
    Sort[data, 
     If[#1[[2]] == #2[[2]], #1[[1]] < #2[[1]], #1[[2]] < #2[[2]]] &];
   Return[
    Reverse[Partition[sdata[[All, component]], 
      Length[DeleteDuplicates[sdata[[All, 1]]]]]]]];`